# Git: Автоматическая синхронизация проекта на разных пк

Tags: git, развертывание

Есть pre-продакшен на VPS, изменения на котором моментально отображаются на стенде. Работа по SSHFS не стабильна и крайне медленна.

Идея в том что бы развернув проект локально, после git push на VPS автоматически подтянулись изменения. И сразу можно было посмотреть изменения на стенде.

На текущий момент, реализовано так что после `git push`, для подтягивания изменений приходится делать `git pull`. Что крайне неудобно. Как можно автоматизировать этот процесс (хотя бы в одностороннем порядке local->push->VPS) ?

Comment: `local->pull` или `local->push`?

Comment: Вообще у вас что за продукт? Просто сайт статический или что-то сложнее? Один хост или инфраструктура? Можно обойтись копированием файлов или нужно устанавливать-конфигурять-связывать?

Comment: Ну и что у вас за сервер гита? Можно зайти по ssh и настроить хуки? Есть ли возможность прикрутить CI? (В GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket точно есть, про остальные надо смотреть, если просто голый репозиторий лежит — то нет, зато наверняка можно по ssh)

Comment: BitBucket  local->push

Answer (score 1):

Можно на сервере гита настроить push hook который будет дергать на VPS скрипт стягивающий последние изменения. Все зависит вашего стека. 
На PHP это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php
echo "<b>Attempting to pull from git repo...</b> <br>";
exec('git pull', $output);
foreach ($output as $o) {
    echo $o . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Этот скрипт на стороне VPS же выполняется? А как его дёрнуть?

Comment: Прописать его полный URL в настройках GIT, куда производится push.

Comment: В данном случае Bitbucket очевидно. https://bitbucket.org/*/*/admin/addon/admin/bitbucket-webhooks/bb-webhooks-repo-admin

Answer (score -3):

Можно настроить простейший [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), который будет ежеминутно делать `git pull`.

```
* * * * * cd path_to_git_root && git pull
```

Comment: не надо. Просто не надо.